# How can I delete everything but an alphanumeric pattern?

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, regular-expression, cut

I have a file that has a lot of junk and special characters as well. I want to keep a particular alphanumeric pattern and ignore everything else - e.g AB123456789 - I want to extract only this keyword i.e. two alphabets 'AB' followed by 9 numbers.

**SAMPLE INPUT:**

[{"u_affected_cis":"m324nkj43nkj3n4kj34n","number":"hhggjjiiijjjf","akdsfj_skdfj":"","as_group":"1,324kj3k4j3k4jk34","order":"","__status":"success","phase":"gfhgh","cmdb_ci":"0989iujlkj","u_benefit_organization":"","u_creating_group":"luiy98798yukuh","work_notes_list":"","priority":"4","u_tier4_location":"","review_date":"","u_mf_batch_inst_opdoc_move":"","u_requesting_group":"kjhljlkjhlkuh098709kjh","business_duration":"","number":"**AB123456789**","requested_by":tgfgtf878789khgo7869876ff9007da158c","u_temp","change_plan":"","asd_def":"2023-02-10 11:58:21","implementation_plan":"","short_description":"data","u_alternate_programmer_work_number":"","work_start":"","u_assignment_group_updated":"","yy_uhggfjk":"","fds":"change_request","closed_by":"abcdef","start_date":"2023-02-10"}]

**SAMPLE OUTPUT:**

AB123456789

Comment: Some sample input & output would go a long ways towards getting a good answer.

Comment: Added sample input and output.

Comment: If your actual input is valid JSON, you would be better served by a JSON-aware tool such as jq, e.g. `jq -r '.[0].number'`.

Comment: I would first fix what ever created this, as it is not valid json (missing " before tgfgtf878789khgo…, u_temp has no value), then use @dhag's solution. And I thing dhag should make the comment into an answer.

Answer (score 2):

If your actual input is valid JSON, you would be better served by a
JSON-aware tool, such as jq:

```
jq -r '.[0].number'.
```

(I say "if", because the input you posted is not valid JSON as it is
missing a double quote and one of the keys has no value attached to
it; I assume that the breakage may have happened as you were preparing
the question.)

Answer (score 0):

If your file has always the same number of fields and your pattern appears at the same location (eg: column 72) you may use a simple awk:

```
awk -F "\"" '{print $72}' input-file.txt
```

It appears that a pattern match is not suitable for you because you have the same pattern (AF123456789) at the beginning of the file.

I hope this answer helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Some sed should do the job:

```
sed -e '/AB[0-9]\{9\}/!d' -e 's/.*\(AB[0-9]\{9\}\).*/\1/'
```

Answer (score -1):

I've created these files to replicate a smaller scale of what you're doing:

```
┌─[root@Fedora]─[~/stack_exchange]─[03:38 pm]
└─[$]› ls
1234fnjfck   CA123456789      EA123456789  HA123456789  KA123456789   NA123456789  QA123456789  TA123456789              VA123456789  YA123456789
AA123456789  DA123456789      FA123456789  IA123456789  LA123456789  OA123456789  RA123456789  testing-please-delete-me  WA123456789  ZA123456789
BA123456789  DELETE1234  GA123456789  JA123456789  MA123456789  PA123456789  SA123456789  UA123456789              XA123456789
```

a regex variable matching the pattern  will be able to handle pulling the desired files that do not match the pattern in a for in loop, with an if statement:

```
┌─[root@Fedora]─[~/stack_exchange]─[04:07 pm]
└─[$]› pattern="^[A-Z][A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$"

[$]› for i in $(ls ~/stack_exchange); do if ! [[ $i =~ $pattern ]]; then echo "$i does not match!"; fi; done
1234fnjfck does not match!
DELETE1234 does not match!
testing-please-delete-me does not match!
```

So to delete them:

```
[$]› for i in $(ls ~/stack_exchange); do if ! [[ $i =~ $pattern ]]; then rm -f $i; fi; done
```

result:

```
[$]› ls
AA123456789  CA123456789  EA123456789  GA123456789  IA123456789  KA123456789  MA123456789  OA123456789  QA123456789  SA123456789  UA123456789  WA123456789  YA123456789
BA123456789  DA123456789  FA123456789  HA123456789  JA123456789  LA123456789  NA123456789  PA123456789  RA123456789  TA123456789  VA123456789  XA123456789  ZA123456789
```

Comment: Deleted the file itself..

Comment: There is nothing about deleting files in the question, so `rm` is the wrong way to go. Also nothing about filenames.

Comment: sorry, I assumed @Koshur wanted to remove them due to the title "How can I delete everything but an alphanumeric pattern?" - also the question was different at the time of answering.